# Animation not starting correctly

Tags: css, animation

What I'm looking for is my marquee to start at the beginning of the looped element; go all the way until the element scrolls off of the screen, then start at the beginning of the element.

Now, the element does get all the way to the end.  It does start up immediately once the element disappears.  But when it starts it either starts the element half way through, or if the browser is in a small state, it'll take a little while for it to start.

```css
.marquee {
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  /*position: relative;*/
}

.marquee div {
  display: block;
  width: fit-content;
  height: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  animation-name: marquee;
  animation-duration: 15s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.marquee div:hover {
  animation-play-state: paused
}

@keyframes marquee {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>

  <div class="marquee">
    <div>
      <p>Some text. Some more text. It's times like these that try mens hearts. We strive to succeed. With hard work, we will. Here will be some various lines to stuff.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, here's what got it to work for me.

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <style>
            .marquee {
                width: 100%;
                margin: 0 auto;
                white-space: nowrap;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
            .marquee div {
                display: inline-block;
                padding-left: 100%;
                text-indent: 0;
                animation-name: animate_the_marquee;
                animation-duration: 15s;
                animation-timing-function: linear;
                animation-iteration-count: infinite;
            }
            .marquee div:hover {
                animation-play-state: paused
            }
            @keyframes animate_the_marquee {
                0% {
                    transform: translateX(0%);
                }
                100% {
                    transform: translateX(-100%);
                }
            }
            </style>
            <div class="marquee">
                <div>Some text. Some more text. It's times like these that try mens hearts.  We strive to <span style="color:green">succeed</span>.  With hard work, we will. Here will be some various lines to stuff.</div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <body>            
         <div class="marquee">
              <div>
                 <p>Some text. Some more text. It's times like these that try mens hearts.  We strive to succeed.  With hard work, we will. Here will be some various lines to stuff.</p>
               </div>
          </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
 .marquee {
          height: 60px;
          width: 100%;
          overflow: hidden;                      
          position:relative;
  }
  .marquee div {
          display: block;
          width: fit-content;
          height: 30px;
          padding-bottom: 15px;
          position: absolute;
          overflow: hidden;
          white-space: nowrap;
          animation-name: marquee;
          animation-duration: 15s;
          animation-timing-function: linear;
          animation-iteration-count: infinite;
   }
   .marquee div:hover {
          animation-play-state: paused
   }
   @keyframes marquee {
           0% {
              transform: translateX(5%);
           }
           100% {
              transform: translateX(-100%);
           }
    }
```

Comment: Gaurav, That only starts it 5% off of the left side.  I want it to slide in from the right side.